# how to get crisp graphics on android device

Tags: android, user-interface, graphics

I'm a visual designer creating a UI for an app for an android tablet. The resolution of the tablet is 1024x600 with a density of 160 - I'm building the UI in photoshop on a 1024x600 72dpi canvas - Is this right? I've seen some previews on the device and the graphics that are super crisp on my monitor are kinda fuzzy on the device. I would have expected them to be even crisper.

The app wont need to support any other devices so its not a question multiple resources -

Can anyone shed some light as to best way to approach? This is my first mobile project so still  learning the ins and outs ; )

Comment: FYI I believe the Galaxy Tab identifies itself as an HDPI device regardless of its actual DPI.

Answer (score 1):

[Guides from Samsung](http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/galaxyTab.do). Bet you also developing for that?

If your UI is in 1024x600 pixels (in photoshop), it should be no problem. I think the problem may come from a few other issue:

1. density of 160 is called mdpi in Android, make sure you put the pictures to drawable-mdpi folder;
2. Are you sure your picture/graphics isn't stretched by the Android layouts? For example, you may have a button in 100x100 px, but in the layout, it is defined like "fill_parent" or "120dip", then, it is stretched and not in native density. The native density for 160 dpi, will be exactly the same as pixel size, (1dip = 1px in 160dpi), so, your button should be "100dip" (or simply use absolute size to get rid of this trouble)
3. I think you may do a simple test, making a 1024x600 px image (PNG), and put this as the background of the activity, and set the activity to be full screen without title bar. It shouldn't have any problem in showing in this way.

One last word, I actually do my final layout in Fireworks, it has better pixel level control in terms of small UI graphics. But photoshop should also able to do the job.

Comment: +1 for Fireworks. Fast, easy, and plenty good enough if you know what you're doing. Photoshop is for heavy image work. If you just need icons and buttons and whatnot, FW fills the bill.

Comment: I actually works heavily on cross applications. Start quick scratch from Illustrator, Production graphic on FW, bitmap graphics back to PS. But final stuff still generated from FW. I like the interface on Illustrator, I just wonder why not like that in FW.

Comment: Haha - nope not samsung ; ) Actually just said photoshop to keep it simple. I use FW exclusively - love it. So ya - that was our theory that if we worked in the resolution of the device that we would be good - and even would get sharper images because of the higher density.